# Setting an image as the background to a specific surface of my 3d plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I have written the following code to plot lat,long and colorbar for temperature within certain height constraints using the following code -

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Path to the combo folder
combo_folder = '/home/dev/Desktop/Venus/Data/combo'

# constraints
height_min = 40
height_max = 60
venus_radius = 6051.8

# Calculate the aspect ratio of the image
# image = plt.imread('/home/dev/Desktop/Venus/Images/venmap2.tif')
image = plt.imread('/home/dev/Desktop/Venus/Images/venmap.gif')
# image = plt.imread(image_path)
image_aspect_ratio = image.shape[1] / image.shape[0]

# Create a figure with dimensions based on the image aspect ratio
width = 30
height = width / image_aspect_ratio
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(width, height))

# Display the image as the background
ax.imshow(image, extent=[0, 360, -90, 90], aspect='auto')

# Iterate over the files in the combo folder
for filename in os.listdir(combo_folder):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        file_path = os.path.join(combo_folder, filename)

        # Load the combined dataset
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

        # Extract the required columns
        latitude = df['LATITUDE']
        longitude = df['LONGITUDE']
        temperature = df['TEMPERATURE_MEDIUM_TEMPERATURE_AT_BOUNDARY']
        height = df['RADIUS'] - venus_radius

        # Filter data based on height constraints
        mask = (height >= height_min) & (height <= height_max)
        latitude = latitude[mask]
        longitude = longitude[mask]
        temperature = temperature[mask]

        # Plot latitude, longitude, and temperature
        scatter = ax.scatter(longitude, latitude, c=temperature,s=200, cmap='viridis', alpha=0.7)
        ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
        ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')
        ax.set_title('Latitude and Longitude with Temperature (Height: {} to {})'.format(height_min, height_max))

# Add a colorbar
cbar = fig.colorbar(scatter, ax=ax, label='Temperature (°C)')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

[2d plot with the image as bg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PricU.jpg)

And, I have the following code which shows the lat,long,height as 3d plot with temp as the colorbar

```
venus_radius = 6051.8

import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Path to the combo folder
combo_folder = '/home/dev/Desktop/Venus/Data/combo'

# Height constraints
height_min = 40
height_max = 60

# Create a figure and a 3D axis
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Set axis limits
ax.set_xlim(0, 360)
ax.set_ylim(-90, 90)
ax.set_zlim(0, 90)

# Iterate over the files in the combo folder
for filename in os.listdir(combo_folder):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        file_path = os.path.join(combo_folder, filename)
        
        # Load the combined dataset
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        
        # Extract the required columns
        latitude = df['LATITUDE']
        longitude = df['LONGITUDE']
        radius = df['RADIUS']
        temperature = df['TEMPERATURE_MEDIUM_TEMPERATURE_AT_BOUNDARY']
        height = radius - venus_radius
        
        # Filter data based on height constraints
        mask = (height >= height_min) & (height <= height_max)
        latitude = latitude[mask]
        longitude = longitude[mask]
        temperature = temperature[mask]
        height = height[mask]
        
        # Plot latitude, longitude, and temperature within the height range
        scatter = ax.scatter(longitude, latitude, height, c=temperature, cmap='viridis', alpha=0.7)
        ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
        ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')
        ax.set_zlabel('Height')
        ax.set_title('Latitude, Longitude, and Height with Temperature (Height: {} to {})'.format(height_min, height_max))
        
# Add a colorbar
cbar = fig.colorbar(scatter, ax=ax, label='Temperature (°C)')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

[3d plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsEyl.png)

The image I am using as the background is -
[the image I am using as background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gghbe.jpg)

I am trying to maintain the aspect ratios in the 2 d plot as it is, just trying to get a plot which integrates the two. essentially the image as the backround of the surface for lat,long, while keeping the aspect ratio settings as in the 2d plot.

Comment: Where are you looking for the image to be placed, on the longitude latitude plane?

Comment: Since you specifically ask about the aspect ratio, see: https://hastebin.com/share/alekobicot.python

Comment: I am trying to use it as the background for the lat long plane

Comment: That's what I show in the linked code.